# How to move a 3D object to a global coordinate AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, displayobject

Let's say I have a movieclip in 3d space, and want to move it to a specific x/y coordinate in global coordinates, but keeping it at it's Z position.  How do I do this? It's much as if you drag an object around on screen in the flash IDE -- if it has a z, you'll see the x/y change.

What I'm trying to do is line up an object "in the distance" in 3d space with another object on stage.

I've tried displayObject.globalToLocal3D() and that works great EXCEPT it gives me z == 0, that is, it moves the 3d object all the way up to z == 0 and then x and y are simply what my stage object' x and y are.

Any help much appreciated!  I'm sure I'm missing the obvious!